# How to prevent frequency table to count ''empty boxes'' in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote the below code (for homework) that is counting letters and numbers and generates a frequency table.
My question is: **how to stop the frequency generation when the letter or number does not exist**?

With the code I wrote, the program is counting every letter that are being fed to it but is also publishing a line for every possible letter/number in the ASCII code.

I hope I asked my question right and I appreciate any help or advice!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int countingLetters(string someWords);

int countingNumbers(string someWords);

int frequency(string someWords, double totalChar);

int main() {
    string someWords;
    cout << "Write a some words: " << endl;
    getline(cin, someWords);
    cout << "You wrote:" << someWords << '\n';

    cout << "Your sentence has " << someWords.length() << " characters." << '\n';

    double totalChar = someWords.length();

    cout << "Your sentence has " << countingLetters(someWords) << " letters." << '\n';

    cout << "Your sentence has " << countingNumbers(someWords) << " numbers." << '\n';

    cout << "Frequency of signs and letters :" << endl;

    frequency(someWords, totalChar);


    return 0;
}

int countingLetters(string someWords) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < someWords.length(); i++) {
        if (someWords[i] >= 'a' && someWords[i] <= 'z')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int countingNumbers(string someWords) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < someWords.length(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(someWords[i]) != 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int frequency(string someWords, double totalChar) {
    cout << " Letter" << '\t' << "Antal" << '\t' << "Procent" << endl;
    int frequency[255]={0};
    for (int i = 0; i < someWords.length(); i++) {
        char c = someWords[i];
        if (isdigit(c) != 0)
            frequency[c]++;
        if (isalpha(c) != 0)
            frequency[c]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(frequency); i++) {
        if(frequency[i]>0)
        cout << '\t' << static_cast<char>(i) << '\t' << frequency[i] << '\t' << frequency[i]/totalChar << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really the problem here, but don't use `double` whe you can use an integer type.

Comment: `sizeof(frequency)` is the size of the array _in bytes_.

Comment: It's unclear to me what do you mean with *"how to stop the frequency generation when the letter or number does not exist"* and the following paragraph. In your code you are considering all of the chars when calculating the total and this affects the percentages. Are you asking how to count only the alphanumeric chars or how to stop the loop when a different char is found?

Comment: In my output, I get my frequency table but also information about all the letters and numbers that are not there. I hope it makes it clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(frequency)` is the size of the `frequency` array in bytes. You want the number of elements which is the size in bytes if the array divided by the size in bytes of one array element:

This is the number of elements of the `frequency` array:

```
sizeof(frequency) / sizeof(frequency[0])
```

But as you are using C++ you shouln't use raw arrays but `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
...
int frequency(string someWords, int totalChar) {
  cout << " Letter" << '\t' << "Antal" << '\t' << "Procent" << endl;
  std::array<int, 255> frequency{0};

  for (int i = 0; i < someWords.length(); i++) {
    char c = someWords[i];
    if (isdigit(c) != 0)
      frequency[c]++;
    if (isalpha(c) != 0)
      frequency[c]++;
  }

  int x = frequency.max_size();

  for (int i = 0; i < frequency.max_size(); i++) {
    if (frequency[i]>0)
      cout << '\t' << static_cast<char>(i) << '\t' << frequency[i] << '\t' << frequency[i] / totalChar << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for improvement.